# Base 8 to X(Base 16) conversion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, number-systems

$475.641_8$ to $X_{16}$

Answer is $13D.D08_{16}$

My attempt: $27BA1_{16}$

Which step I had missed?

Thanks.

Comment: How can anyone possibly say what your error was when you don't show us what you did?

Comment: I convert to binary then to base 16

Comment: A good idea, so did you get $1 0011 1101.1101 0000 1000$ as the binary

Comment: Then you divide into groups of 4 starting from the decimal point: $1|0011|1101.1101|0000|1000$ which gives you $13D.D08$.

Comment: Ah no, I get 00100111101.110100001

Comment: It looks like you treated the decimal point as a thousands separator.  Your attempt is correct in that interpretation.  But it looks like they're treading the decimal point as a radix.

Answer (score 1):

The question assumes 475.641 is not a whole number. The dot separates the fractional part from the integer part. Converting to binary you get $|100|111|101.110|100|001$. Now you convert to hex, starting from the decimal point, so the first step is to regroup the digits into groups of four: $0001|0011|1101.1101|0000|1000$. Now you convert to hex digits to get $13D.D08$.